# Using Javascript namespace closures and prototype together fails?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm using namespacing in my projects by folllowing this pattern:

```
// simply a namespace attic object
// parent to my worker objects
;(function( RoaringSky, undefined ) 
{
    var opt = {
        backend : ""
    },
    name = ""
    ;

    RoaringSky.init = function( options ) {
       jQuery.extend(opt,options);
       console.log( 'RoaringSky.init complete');
    };
    // accessor 
    RoaringSky.opt = opt;

})(window.RoaringSky = window.RoaringSky || {});
```

And a child object of this namespace so:

```
RoaringSky.Day = (function() {

    // constructor
    var Day = function(){

        var id = "none";
        var name = "none";
        var date = "none";
        var periods = new Array();

        this.periods = function() {
            return periods;
        };
    };

    // invoking day.time() fails - is not a function message
    Day.prototype.time = function() {
        return this.doSomthingWithDate(date);
    };


    return Day;
})(window.RoaringSky.Day = window.RoaringSky.Day || {});
```

The pattern works fine as far as it goes, I think. (critiques welcome)  But it seems to cock-block use of the prototype property.

Maybe my understanding is incomplete (I'm sure it is) but AFAIK, once I've created an object
- like my Day class above - I ought to be able to write functions in the manner of:

```
Day.prototype.time = function() {
    return this.doSomthingWithDate(date);
};
```

and all instances of the class would inherit the function as it is a property of the constructor's class object, Day();

However, when I try this:

```
var day = new Day();
day = new Date();
console.log( 'day.time: '+ day.time() );
```

I get back the blessed, 'day.time() is not a function'  error message.

What am I doing wrong? This is starting to drive me nuts.

- Erik

Comment: I believe it should be `var day = new RoaringSky.Day();`, you are also overwriting `day` with a `new Date();`, and `time` is not a function on the `Date` object.

Comment: When you do `day = new Date();`, nothing remains on `day` of whatever you were doing with the `Day` class. Calling `time` on it isn't going to work for the same reason it doesn't work normally when you call it on a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems:

```
RoaringSky.Day = (function() {

    // constructor
    var Day = function(){

        var id = "none";
        var name = "none";
        var date = "none";
        var periods = new Array();

        this.periods = function() {
            return periods;
        };
    };

    // invoking day.time() fails - is not a function message
    Day.prototype.time = function() {
        // can't use "date" here since it is not in scope
        return this.doSomthingWithDate(date);
    };


    return Day;
})(window.RoaringSky.Day = window.RoaringSky.Day || {});
```

Then:

```
var day = new Day(); // Day is not a member of window, so this will only work when used in the `RoaringSky.Day` declaration.
day = new Date();    // you then override the day variable for some reason
console.log( 'day.time: '+ day.time() ); // time is not a function member of Date
```